# Can't get service to start on chef

Tags: ruby, service, installation, sinatra, chef-infra

I have a service resource but I can't get chef to start it, instead chef just spits out an error message:

`SystemCallError: The specified service does not exist as an installed service. - OpenService: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`

I'm not sure what to do to fix this and I can't find anything on this error (could be I'm not looking in the right place).

The service is distributed as a gem that's installed.
The service itself is a Sinatra app that uses the `win32-service` gem to start it as a service
The platform is windows server (I know but I have no choice, I have to use windows server)

The code in the chef recipe for this service is:

```
service service_name do
  init_command ("#{%x(gem env gemdir).strip.gsub('/','\\')}\\gems\\#{service_name}-#{installing_version}")
  start_command "rake service:start"
  stop_command "rake service:stop"
  reload_command "rake service:reload"
  restart_command "rake service:restart"
  supports start: true, restart: true, reload: true
  action [:enable,:start]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with Chef, but with your service itself.  Typically when I'm in this situation, I will login manually and attempt to start the service.  Sometimes that will give you additional information.  Also, take a look at the log files for your app and see if you can figure out why it's not starting.

Ultimately, Chef just calls your init and start commands, but it can't do much if those commands fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get a remote connection to the server and looked around. What appears to be happening is that, chef installs my gem to chef embedded ruby but when it starts my gem it starts it using the system ruby (which is both separate and a different version). I'll try removing the ruby that's installing and hopefully it will use the one that comes with chef.

Comment: I forgot to add, the reason your messaged helped was because, after looking through the logs I noticed that it was booting but going no further. The last time I saw that it was becuase it wasn't able to require the main files, since that problem was fixed it could only mean that it couldn't find the gems, I looked and lo and behold the gems were installed (along with my gem) in the embedded ruby rather then the system ruby.

Comment: @user3536548 Do you install your app using chef_gem or gem_package ? chef_gem is intended to install gem into chef stack (mysql-gem to  make request to db within a recipe for exemple) and gem_package goal is to install gems into system ruby, so should work for your need, but sometimes under windows, chef ruby is took for gem_package instead...

Comment: I'm using `gem_package` and your right, about the chef ruby being taken as the system ruby, I'm guessing that for some reason the installed ruby is only being set after the main gem is installed. That said I found I had to re-do file selection for the gem spec as the target machine doesn't have git installed (and ruby mine creates a gem-spec that uses git for the files) which was affecting the bundle command.